# Pander with ftable and quotation marks in output

Tags: r, pander

im trying to get a lovely 3-way crosstable using ftable with pander. In general output is ok, but row and column names are all in quotation marks which isnt ideal.

example:

```
library(pander)
varA <-c("a","a","a","a","b","b")
varB <-c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
varC <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

tab1<-ftable(table(varA,varB,varC))
pander(tab1)
```

Im not sure how i can insert formated table so it wouldnt look awful (copy paste does some wierd things with it), but after knitring it looks like on screenshot below:

[image]

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a bug, so thanks for reporting this -- hopefully [fixed](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/995796ec24a05fbe8c34b9ae7f5547bb652e357c) now:

```
> pander(tab1)

---- ---- ---- - - - - - -
          varC 1 2 3 4 5 6

varA varB                 

 a    1        1 0 1 0 0 0

      2        0 1 0 1 0 0

 b    1        0 0 0 0 1 0

      2        0 0 0 0 0 1
---- ---- ---- - - - - - -
```

[image]

Please try the [development version installed from GitHub](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation) and feel free to report similar issues or any suggestion you may have in the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues).

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm, though i must say im little surprised. I assumed its something with ftable and not a bug in pander. I was trying to do the same with `print(xtable())` but i was getting same double quotations.

Comment: @MaciejKarczewski I think `xtable` also uses `format` in the background, which does the quoting -- see `xtable.format.args` option there.